# Postgres pg_dump Como hacer un backup con poco espacio

Tags: linux, postgresql

Tengo un Servidor **`Centos 6.9`** **`con Postgres 9.2`** y una base que pesa *70 GB* tengo poco espacio disponible y no puedo agregarle más espacio. Necesito hacer un `backup` de la base. El problema es cuando se ejecuta el **`pg_dump`** se corta el proceso por falta de memoria. La pregunta es: ¿hay alguna posibilidad de extraer la base y restaurarla en otro lado?. Hago el `backup` remoto, pero me sigue dando el error. Perdonen por estas preguntas ya que soy nuevo con `Postgres`.
ejecuto:

```
pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -F c -b -v -f "/ruta/respaldo.backup" mybase
```

muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Que error te da exactamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Puedes tratar de hacer un tunnel hacía esa máquina hacía ese puerto y restaurarla o hacer un respaldo desde cualquier otra. Desde tu máquina de preferencia crea un tunnel hacía esa otra máquina donde tienes la base de datos.

   Haces este tuneleo que hace pasar el tráfico del puerto 5432 de la máquina remota a la local, en el puerto 5432 local.

   ```
   $ ssh -N -f -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 <usuario_de_maquina_remota>@<ip_remota>
   ```

   Una vez conectando los puertos de ambas máquinas, puedes correr en cualquier máquina donde hiciste esto

   ```
   $ pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -b -v -f "/ruta/respaldo.backup" dbname
   ```

   Y el respaldo se guardará en cualquier otra donde corras estos comandos.
   Aquí la máquina remota es la que tiene tu base de datos y la local es en la que quieres restaurar o hacer un respaldo.
2. Puedes mandar ese respaldo a otra máquina y restaurarla ahí corriendo este comando en tu máquina donde tengas la base de datos y teniendo accesos por `ssh` a la máquina (claramente con memoria suficiente) remota.

   ```
   $ pg_dump -C -v -h localhost -p 5432 -U user dbname | bzip | ssh  <usuario_remoto>@>host_remoto> "bunzip2 | psql dbname"
   ```

   Aquí la máquina remota es a la que le vas a enviar la base de datos comprimida y luego la vas a restaurar en el *one-liner* y la local es en la que tienes la base de datos.

Claro que tienes que tener accesos por `ssh` en ambas máquinas desde ambas máquinas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! por tu pronta respuesta!!.. Voy a probar y les comento como me fue!! Gracias!!!

Comment: Me olvide de agradecer y decirles que pude hacerlo con sus indicaciones... Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Ivox Si la respuesta que te proporcioné fue la adecuada, no olvides marcarla como la correcta y/o darle un voto positivo para que otra persona que tenga la misma duda pueda reconocer con facilidad que esta respuesta funcionó para dudas iguales o semejantes.

Comment: Gracias!! ya la marque!. Saludos!